# How to trim leading zeros of each value in a concatenated field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, trim

I have a requirement as below.

Input:

```
00113|0267|0139
```

Expected Output:

```
113|267|139
```

Input is directly coming from a file and it's not a generated field

As of now i am using below code to split the filed into multiple values, then trimming it using `Patindex` and `Substring` functions, finally concatenating them again

```
Substring(col, 1,charindex('|',col)-1) part1,
Substring(col,charindex('|',col)+1,(charindex('|', col, charindex('|', col, 1)+1)-charindex('|',col)-1)) part2,
Substring(col,charindex('|', col, charindex('|', col, 1)+1)+1,len(col)) part3
```

Let me know if there is any better way to achieve this without using these many string parsing functions

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Sql server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
declare @i int = 0

while (patindex('%|0%', '|'+@str) > 0)
begin
    set @str = ( replace(substring('|'+ @str, 1, patindex('%|0%', '|'+@str)+1 ), '|0', '|') + substring(@str, patindex('%|0%', '|'+@str)+1, len(@str)) )
    set @i += 1
end

select stuff(@str, 1, @i, '')
```

you can also use `string_split` like below:

```
select STUFF((SELECT  '|' + convert(varchar(100), convert(int, nullif(value, '')))
                  FROM string_split(@str, '|') t
                   FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '') Grouped_Value
```

please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2276286a230dbda62efb2ef967feadc4)**.

Answer (score 0):

one option is to simply use replace()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('00113|0267|0139')

Select * 
      ,NewVal = stuff(replace(replace(replace('|'+SomeCol,'|0','|'),'|0','|'),'|0','|'),1,1,'')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol          NewVal
00113|0267|0139  113|267|139
```

Comment: if it is having more than 3 leading zeros, we need to keep on adding 'n' no. of replace functions

Comment: @Varma Correct.  I assumed no more than three.  There are other options of parsing the string, converting to int and then re-assemble the string.   I was going for a quick and simple solution